# google map directions - setting a custom route

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, mobile

I have a problem with my code logic, The logic I have been seeing so far from the  tutorial and documents is finding the shortest route. I want to ignore the shortest route, I want the vehichle to calculate the distance of my desired route. I want the bus to go around the blue marker but it always finds the shortest distance (refer to this pic) --> [Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT9dr.jpg) [SearchBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HZWq.jpg)

```
import React from 'react';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';

import { PinchGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'API_KEY';

const RouteMap = ({ origin, destination }) => {

  const originLoc = {
    latitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lat,
    longitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lng,
  };

  const destinationLoc = {
    latitude: destination.details.geometry.location.lat,
    longitude: destination.details.geometry.location.lng,
  };

  // latitude - longitude
  const smClark = {
    latitude: 15.166958649105302,
    longitude: 120.58020821518215
  };

  const crkAirport = {
    latitude: 15.188257381909379,
    longitude: 120.54864679960974
  };
  
  const puregold = {
    latitude: 15.193613083464797,
    longitude: 120.5301874657224
  };

  const royceHotel = {
    latitude: 15.180685277215424,
    longitude: 120.52912493815806
  };

  const mGate_1 = {
    latitude: 15.166953827506548,
    longitude: 120.58283672474597
  };

  const mGate_2 = {
    latitude: 15.167813741260368,
    longitude: 120.5829972483142
  };

  
  
  return ( 
    <MapView
      style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      // showsUserLocation={true}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 15.166958649105302,
        longitude: 120.58020821518215,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.015,
        }}
      zoomControlEnabled
        >


      
      {/* Marker dynamic */}
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={originLoc}
        destination={destinationLoc}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={7}
        strokeColor="black"
        />

      
      {/* Loop 1 - Marker */}
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={smClark}
        destination={crkAirport}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeColor="blue"
        />
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={crkAirport}
        destination={puregold}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeColor="blue"
        />
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={puregold}
        destination={royceHotel}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeColor="blue"
        />
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={royceHotel}
        destination={mGate_1}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeColor="blue"
        />
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={mGate_1}
        destination={mGate_2}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeColor="blue"
        />
      
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={mGate_2}
        destination={smClark}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeColor="blue"
        />
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default RouteMap;
```

Comment: You need to be making only one request, but use waypoints. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#waypoints

Comment: Please dont share your API keys in public websites for security purposes as this is considered as PII (Personal Identifiable Information). Please restrict them as well as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restrict_apikey